# How do I identify the value of a crystal oscillator?

Tags: rf, identification, oscillator, frequency-measurement

How do I discover the frequency of a two-pin (to be used with two through holes) silver crystal oscillator which is inscribed with only:

```
   (Top)
  T447.725  
   18  12
   |    |
   |    | (two terminal pins)
```

The part looks like the image below except with the above inscriptions:

[image]

I have searched for the BOM and any documentation for the product (a remote key) in both electronic and paper formats. I discovered that either no product documentation was made or that the product documentation was lost.

i already tried attaching an oscilloscope to the pins, which did not display the frequency of the crystal (as expected.)

Search engines (Google, etc.) gave no indications that a two-pin crystal oscillator with a frequency of 447.725 MHz exists.

Complication: The crystal oscillator MUST match the 447.725 MHz SAW resonator (ITF 4471 18E059.) I found as a "SAW Bandpass Filter ITF F4471" which is apparently no longer produced.

Comment: Why not upload an actual picture of the actual component. That might provide some clues which you are not aware of. Also, just "attaching an oscilloscope" without any other supporting power source etc is unlikely to magically make any module start working. What exactly was your test setup ? The part which you HAVE shown is a simple crystal, NOT a crystal oscillator.

Comment: Better yet also post a picture of the PCB where it was found, including surrounding components. SAW filters tend to have ground so I'd expect at least 3 pins. Also in that case you'd find series caps and/or inductors next to it. I would wildly guess that this is rather a 447.725kHz crystal 18pF load 12ppm.

Comment: I don't know if this should be an answer, but with a lot of time and investigation of old archives, I think the part in question is a 447.725kHz crystal according to some old receipts the company left behind. The seller is gone as far as I can tell, and further investigation was discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry about the question.

We were able to find an old receipt that held what we believe is the parts involved.

Using the receipt, we *think* its a 447.725 kHz crystal.

I do not know why or how people came to that conclusion considering that there were multiple oscillators and crystals listed on the receipt and there are no indication that part in question is the same one on the existing PCB.

But no one is really explaining the reason in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Considering the markings on the crystal oscillator, it seems plausible.